# Rendering a Django block when clicking a sidebar button

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to create a management website with Django. I've got the basic functionality working, but I have trouble rendering content "dynamically". I want to render a block based on clicking a button.

Currently, I have an employee view that renders certain event-objects as a tree. I'm using Django's mptt library for building the tree.

**employeeView**

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class employeeView(View):

    def get(self, request, user_id):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user=request.user
            nodes = Event.objects.filter(owner=user)


        return render(request, "employee_view.html", {'user': user, 'nodes': nodes})
```

**employee_template.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<title>Your events</title>

  These are your events
  {% load mptt_tags %}
<ul>
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li>
            <b>{{ node.name }} </b>
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Then I have a manager view, that currently returns the employees who are managed by the manager, and all events associated to them.

**managerView**

```
class managerView(View):

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda i: u.myuser.isManager))
    def get(self, request, user=None, myuser=None):
         if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = request.user

             ...

         return render(request, "supervisor_view.html", {'user': user, 'employees': employees, "nodes": nodes,})
```

Everything works as intended so far. The managed employees are given to the manager template, and rendered on a sidebar. Below is a snippet of my manager template. It contains a main view block and a sidebar block. The main view is currently empty, but by default it should show some metadata on the employees. This is fairly simple to implement. When an employees name is clicked on the sidebar, I'd like for the mainView block to render that employees "event tree", i.e., to render the employee template for the employee whose name was clicked. How do I do this?

**manager_template.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block leftbarEmployees %}
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="header">Your employees</li>
    {% for employee in employees %}
        <li><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <span>{{ employee }}</span></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block mainView %}
   <!-- the default mainView will just be some metadata gathered from
the passed nodes etc. -->     
{% endblock%}
```

I've been reading django's docs on how to do this, specifically about the include tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include Would that be a good approach to this problem? I'm a little unsure on how to pass the information of the employee whose name was clicked to the include tag

Comment: DO you want to load the page after clicking on particular employee link?

Comment: I'd prefer not to, and I suspect there's a way to do it without loading the whole page after each click.

Comment: You could use pjax for instance https://github.com/eventials/django-pjax. It gives you a nice way to reload part of the page without reloading full page and keeps browser history. Otherwise you could implement simple ajax view which will return you rendered template with context you need and then replace content on frontend side.